# What is the best tool to your knowledge for CSS live editing?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using FireBug, and it is absolutely amazing. The only problem is that it's not really working for IE/Chrome.

What do you guys and girls use?

I'm looking for some tool that will allow me to get live visual feedback for my changes.

**EDIT:** I'm working on IE7 and Firebug Lite conflicts with my other loaded JS scripts.

Thanks

Comment: An IDE with one-keypress saving/uploading, and the `F5` key

Comment: firebug lite for none-ff browsers man

Comment: It's a shame that Chrome and IE haven't refined their developer tools to a standard even remotely close to Firebug. I tend to do the same thing that Pekka recommends when testing outside of Firefox.

Comment: Who else thinks that Firebugs NEEDS a feature to 'commit' changes to the server? that would be awesome.

Comment: Skybound Stylizer is the closest thing to what you're asking for (afaik). According to the website, you can download a trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) works in IE6+ and Chrome. You can also use IE8 Developer Tools and Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2):

"Developer Toolbar" is great for Internet Explorer (although I've heard that the new IE9 should have something new on board).

Chrome has some developer tools builtin. They are pretty similar to Firebug and you can access them by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + J.

Comment: That's 'ctrl + shift + i' for Chrome/Chromium (on Ubuntu 10.10, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it myself (`CTRL + S` / `F5` works for me), but you should check out [***Skybound Stylizer***](http://www.skybound.ca/).

Here's a quote:

> Stylizer's real-time CSS development
>   extends to 9 different integrated web
>   browsers. On Windows, Google Chrome,
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8, and
>   Firefox 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.6 are
>   supported. On Mac, Safari is
>   supported.
>
> ..
>
> The Stylizer workflow couldn't be
>   easier. Just open up the URL or the
>   HTML page you want to edit, the style
>   sheets are automatically extracted
>   from the page, and you're ready to
>   start making changes.

Other than that:

**Firefox** - Firebug

**Internet Explorer 8/9** - Developer Tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>) (you can [download it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) for IE7/IE6)

**Chrome/Safari** - Developer Tools

**Opera** - Dragonfly

For Chrome/Safari/Opera, I just right click anywhere on the page and click "Inspect Element".

Answer (score 0):

"Developer toolbar" for IE (although not as good as firebug). Im sure there must be a similar add on for chrome too.